# Problema con el resultado de la paradoja del Cumpleaños en Java

Tags: java

He tratado de resolver la paradoja del cumpleaños, pero algún error tengo en el código, que no me lo arroja de forma correcta.

La paradoja consiste en calcular la probabilidad de que dos o más personas cumplan los años el mismo día entre un grupo determinado

Os pongo la clase Paradoja del Cumpleaños:

```
public class ParadojaDelCumpleaños {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el número de personas: ");
        int poblacion = (entrada.nextInt());
        System.out.println(cumple(poblacion));
        entrada.next();
    }


    public static double cumple(int num) {
        double probabilidad = 1.0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            probabilidad = probabilidad * 366 / 365;
        }

        return (100 * ((1 - probabilidad)));
    }
}
```

Alguien podría ayudarme ? graciassss

Comment: Que error obtiene al mostrar los resultados ?

Comment: El for te está arrojando (366/365) elevado a la potencia del valor de num.

Comment: Me da valores que no concuerdan con los del ejercicio original. Jean Gotopo, no entiendo lo que dices

Comment: La cuestión es que ese valor es solo una parte para el cálculo de la solución. Voy a intentar darte una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la posible solución:

public class ParadojaDelCumpleaños {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el número de personas: ");
    int poblacion = (entrada.nextInt());
    System.out.println(cumple(poblacion));
    entrada.next();
}


public static double cumple(int num) {
    double probabilidad = 1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        probabilidad = probabilidad * (366-i) / 365;
    }

    return (100 * ((1 - probabilidad)));
}
```

}

**Explicación Teórica**

La Paradoja del Cumpleaños es un problema muy estudiado en el área de las Estadísticas y Probabilidades. Esta establece que  que de un conjunto de 23 personas, hay una probabilidad del 50,7% de que al menos dos de ellas cumplan años el mismo día. Para 57 o más personas la probabilidad es mayor del 99,666%. En sentido estricto esto no es una paradoja ya que no es una contradicción lógica; sin embargo, es una verdad matemática que contradice la intuición común. Mucha gente piensa que la probabilidad es mucho más baja, y que hacen falta muchas más personas para que se alcance la probabilidad del 50,666%.

La probabilidad de que dos personas tengan diferentes cumpleaños es 364/365 (porque para cualquier persona, en 365 días para elegir su cumpleaños, solo hay 1 día que hace que esta persona tenga el mismo cumpleaños que la otra persona). La probabilidad de que la tercera persona tenga un cumpleaños diferente al de las dos primeras es 363/365; la cuarta persona es 362/365; y así sucesivamente, la 24ª persona es 342/365.

**Explicación del Código**

Ahora bien, respecto al código, precisamente el `for` hace eso que menciona el anterior párrafo, es decir restando la cantidad de personas y multiplicando por su valor anterior, según la cantidad de personas a considerar. Todo ello obedece a la fórmula encontrada para calcular dicha probabilidad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues muchas gracias a los dos, me había quedado ese pequeño y molesto matiz que me lleva loca tres días. ¡Y no me había dado cuenta!. Graciassss

Comment: Por favor, explica brevemente qué hace este código. Puede que el OP (autor de la pregunta) haya entendido, pero otros usuarios verán más adelante el código y _no entenderán qué sucede_.

Comment: Listo, explicación añadadida.